# Confluent go kafka library starting from earliest offsets on restart

Tags: go, apache-kafka, confluent-platform

We currently use Kafka 0.8.2 for our brokers. We use the .Poll() method to grab messages and commit after we collect 1000 messages. We are able to consume from the cluster fine using this library, and I can see that the offsets are being stored in the __consumer_offsets topic from a manual commit call. However, when the consumer restarts, it does not use the stored offsets. It instead restarts from the earliest offsets (I have auto.offset.reset=earliest). Do I need to do something specific to force Kafka to use these offsets instead of looking in Zookeeper, or should the consumer take care of that? Is there a way I can force the consumer to write offsets to Zookeeper instead of the __consumer_offsets topic?

Comment: Zookeeper stored offsets are deprecated last I saw, so I wouldn't go that route. Kind of an obvious question but are you specifying your consumer group as the same value each time?

Comment: If you WANT to use the latest offsets (the ones stored in the offsets topic), why are you using auto.offset.reset=earliest? You should be using latest, unless I misunderstand your situation...

Comment: @Moonwalkr auto.offset.reset value will not be considered unless group.id is also reassigned.

Comment: @Thomas I don't think it's deprecated with the Kafka version in the question

Comment: @Thomas yes the same group id is specified each time